# Return the last record in a One to many Eloquent Relation using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Assuming there existed a `One To Many` relation where a User has Many Jobs, and the last record in the `job` table is the current job of the user. What is a better way of returning the users with their last jobs?

Here is what I have tried.

`User Class`

```
public function ejob(){
   return $this->hasMany(Ejob::class);
}
```

`Ejob Class`

```
public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

`API Controller Method`

```
public function index()
{
  return UserResource::collection(( 
  User::with(
          $this->particulars() // I want the last record from this line
        )->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get() ));
}
```

`Particulars Method`

```
// I want the last record from this
private function particulars(){
        return 
        [
            'ejob.company:id,name', 
            'ejob.job:id,title', 
            'ejob.department:id,name',
            'ejob.reporting:id,surname,first_name,other_name',
            'ejob.employmentstatus:id,name', 
            'country:id,name', 
            'gender:id,name', 
            'state:id,name'
        ];
}
```

`User Resource`

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        //return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
            'data' => [
                'id' => $this->id,
                'surname' => $this->surname,
                'first_name' => $this->first_name,
                'other_name' => $this->other_name,
                'email' => $this->email,
                'phone_number' => $this->phone_number,
                'birthday' => $this->birthday->format('d-m-Y'),
                'age'=> $this->birthday->age,
                'ejob' => $this->whenLoaded('ejob'),
        ];
    }
```

Currently, this returns a user with all related records from the `ejobs` table but I want just the last job.

Comment: have you tried `->last()` on a collection object?

Comment: Yeah... `->last()` on the collection object returns only one user with the user relation

Comment: I would recommend writing a method in your user model to get the latest job.

Comment: I considered that but preferred something else

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could define another relationship method for the same relationship but define it as a Has One instead of a Has Many:

```
public function currentJob()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Ejob::class, ...)->latest();
   // order by by how ever you need it ordered to get the latest
}
```

Then you could eager load that instead of the `ejob` relationship where needed.

Comment: I already tried this and it works... Felt I should try something else...

Comment: there isn't something else unless you want to add joins to the relationship to limit the results per parent record

Comment: I just want to get the first latest item,, I dont want to get everything.

Comment: This option was the generic solution but not the most effective. Since we query lots of records just to select the latest one, this is a n+1 issue.

Comment: This is prone to unexpected results, latestOfMany() is the way to go for this. latest() will not cause exceptions but it will give you inconsistent/misleading results. Please consider updating the answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
// in your case

public function currentJob()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Ejob::class, ...)->latestOfMany();
   // order by by how ever you need it ordered to get the latest
}

// another example 

public function latestPerformance()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Performance::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `first()` instead of `get()`. So it'll get a single model instance.
`get()` method give a collection and `first()` method give you a single model instance.

```
User::with(
          $this->particulars()
        )->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()
```

Or you can use `latest()` to get the last inserted record.

```
User::with(
          $this->particulars()
        )->latest()->first()
```

`->latest()` fetches the most recent set of data from the Database. In short, it sorts the data fetched, using the `created_at` column to chronologically order the data.

**Edit:-**

As you wanted to get the last record of the relationship you can do as below.

```
User::with('ejob', function($query) {
    return $query->latest()->first();
})->get();
```

Comment: `->first()` returns only record from the `users` table and no record from the `jobs` table. I will update my question with the `User Resource` I want the `users` with their last jobs from the `jobs` table

Comment: I think your answer will give first or latest user but thats not what OP whats (afaik).  OP wants all the user's latest/current jobs

Answer (score 0):

You can group it by GROUP BY and then return all results.
There you will see job for each User