# how to join two tables in mysql one with multiple records of forign key

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables as distributor and the other as distributor_status. The distributor goes through multiple stages of status so I have used a sep table for distributor status as

table: distributor

```
ID
distributor name
```

table: distributor_status

```
id
distributor_id
status
```

The rows in each table is as:

| id | distributor_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | RN Ent |
| 2 | M2 Ent |

The status table for distributor 1 is as

| id | distributor_id | status | status_changed_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | New | 2022-05-10 |
| 2 | 1 | Verification Process | 2022-05-10 |
| 3 | 1 | Approved | 2022-05-11 |

The SQL join should get distributor 1 with the latest status i.e in my case it should be status_id as 3 with status Approved

What should be query to get the below result set?

| id | distributor_name | status | status_changed_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EN Ent | Approved | 2022-05-11 |

Comment: I found a brilliant method of doing this join here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59353057/return-the-last-record-in-a-one-to-many-eloquent-relation-using-laravel

Answer (score 2):

We can use a join along with the `RANK()` analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT d.id, d.distributor_name, ds.status, ds.status_changed_on,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY d.id
                        ORDER BY ds.status_changed_on DESC) rnk
    FROM distributor d
    LEFT JOIN distributor_status ds
        ON ds.distributor_id = d.id
)

SELECT id, distributor_name, status, status_changed_on
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

Note that in the event of two or more entries for a given distributor being tied for the most recent event, all such records would be returned.